# Netbeans -> How to run a file with specific arguments and specific environmental variables?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, netbeans-8

I just moved from Eclipse to latest netbeans 8.1.

Please refer to the following photo from Eclipse:

[image]

As you can see, I can select a file in the Main Tab. Then set its arguments in the "Arguments" tab and also the environmental variables for this specific file run in the "Environment Tab"

How can I do the same with Netbeans?

Thanks,

Qwerty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options available for different project types. The options are found after selecting the `Run` category in the project properties dialog. Although not all project types specifically include environment settings. There are a number of easy ways to get increased flexibility in the run environment.

- Use a bash script for Linux or Mac or a .bat batch file for Windows. With C/C++ support enabled, you can right-click and run any .sh/.bat file in the Files or Favorites tab. It is very nice since you or your users can use it outside netbeans. Note: The project doesn't need to be C++ but convenient run feature comes with the C++ support.
- For Java projects, use the exec task for Ant. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html or the exec plugin for maven to add http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html to edit the build.xml or pom.xml file to add a target/goal. All of the goals/targets can be run from the navigator window.

This would be an example that could be added to the build.xml.

```
<target name="myspecialrun" depends="MyJavaProject-impl.jar">
    <exec  executable="printenv">
        <arg value="MYENVVAR"/>
         <env key="MYENVVAR" value="MYENVVAL"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. I need it for Python.